# What is the difference between a space between two functions and using the composition operator?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, composition

I was trying to define a function that determines if a number is a multiple of 3, I first did the easy case

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (==0) (rem num 3)
```

but actually even in that simple case, my first guess was to write my solution like

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (==0).(rem num 3)
```

which returns the error

> Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Integral (a -> b) (Use
> FlexibleContexts to permit this) When checking that
> ‘isMultipleOfThree’ has the inferred type   isMultipleOfThree ::
> forall b a.
> (Eq b, Integral (a -> b), Num b) =>
> (a -> b) -> a -> Bool

and then tried to make it more "polymorphic":

The correct answer was as follows, but I thought that I was supposed to use a space instead of the composition operator... and then I just "guessed" I would try with the composition operator:

```
esMultiploDeTres = (==0).(flip (rem) 3)
```

So I guess that I would add to my original question: "what is a space between two functions?"

Comment: Not strictly a duplicate, but [this](/questions/940382/what-is-the-difference-between-dot-and-dollar-sign) question and its answers should shed some light. Note that that is about `(.)` vs `($)` but apart from precedence `$` is basically the same as a space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(.)` is defined simply as

```
# Apply g to x, then apply f to the result.
f . g = \x -> f (g x)
```

which means

```
(f . g) x == f (g x)
```

Juxtaposition represents function *application*, while the `.` represents function *composition*.

Higher-order functions, such as `(.)`, can take other functions as arguments, which means you can apply such a function to another function. `f . g` is an infix expression, equivalent to the prefix expression `(.) f g`, where `(.)` is applied to `f`, and that result is applied to `g`.

Answer (score 3):

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (==0) (rem num 3)
```

The `(== 0)` is called an operator section. It's equivalent to `\x -> x == 0`, hence this is the same as

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (\x -> x == 0) (rem num 3)
```

And we immediately apply the lambda, so we get

```
isMultipleOfThree num = rem num 3 == 0
```

Now, on the other hand, your second example is

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (\x -> x == 0) . (rem num 3)
```

Now we're *not* applying the lambda immediately. We're applying the `(.)` function, which is defined something like

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> c)
f . g = \y -> f (g y)
```

Hence, we have

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (\y -> (\x -> x == 0) ((rem num 3) y))
```

Now the lambda on `x` is getting applied to an argument, so we can simplify the inner one

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (\y -> (rem num 3) y == 0)
```

And the parentheses around `rem` are extraneous, hence

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (\y -> rem num 3 y == 0)
```

So we're applying `rem`, a function of two arguments, to three arguments. Hence your error.

If you want to use `(.)` to define your function, we can. But the right-hand side needs to have an argument left out.

```
isMultipleOfThree = (== 0) . (\x -> rem x 3)
```

or

```
isMultipleOfThree = (== 0) . (`rem` 3)
```

Note that we don't mention your function argument `num` anymore. The composition on the right-hand side is expecting an argument. It's going to do (`rem` 3)`on that argument and then compare the result against zero.`(.)`works on functions, and both sides of the`(.)` operator should have an argument missing.

Note that what you might have been thinking of is `($)`, which is defined roughly as

```
($) :: (a -> b) -> (a -> b)
f $ x = f x
```

This really is just function application. It's not composition. We could easily write your original function as

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (== 0) $ (rem num 3)
```

The `($)` actually does behave like juxtaposition. The only point of it is to change operator precedence. We can omit parentheses in this case

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (== 0) $ rem num 3
```

and this will still work, whereas if we omit parentheses in your original function

```
isMultipleOfThree num = (==0) rem num 3 -- Wrong!
```

Now we're trying to apply the `(==0)` function to *three* arguments, which is definitely not correct.